Adding placeholder when type="number" and defaultvalue, react-hook-form
Hey so this is my schema:
const SecondFormSchema = z.object({
  trainingType: z.enum(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "FullBody"]),
  trainingName: z.string().min(2),
  exercises: z
    .array(
      z.object({
        coachNotes: z.string().min(2),
        repsNumber: z.number().int().min(1),
        setsNumber: z.number().int().min(1),
        restTime: z.optional(z.number().int().min(1)),
        exerciseDetails: z.string(),
      }),
    )
    .nonempty({ message: "Please add at least one exercise" }),
});

but when I add new exercise to the array I append like this:
  <Button
    type="button"
    onClick={() =>
      append({
        coachNotes: "",
        repsNumber: 0,
        setsNumber: 0,
        restTime: 0,
        exerciseDetails: "",
      })
    }
  >
    Add Exercise
  </Button>

the append demands defaultValues, so the restTime, setsNumber and repsNumber do not have their placeholder but instead a 0 value. I tried with form.Setvalue but can't set value to undefined to get the placeholder because they are numbers, according to the zod schema

it's not obvius for me that what is your problem exactly, and what do you want to change with setValue and why.  Do you want to set default value for your arrays item that accept 0 and empty "" ?

I just want to have undefined instead of a number, because when I try to append with undefined typescript throws an error. if I set the value as 0 when I append new values, the placeholder is vanished. I wnat basically to use the placeholder. is it possible or I should use label?

So, for example: you want to set coachNote to a string (with max 2 length) OR undefined ?

Why optional() doesn't help you?

What do you mean placeholder and label, I haven't seen any of these on your code

a regular placeholder in the input field. and label a regular label in the form. its a form i will edit and show the input. i want it to be number or undefined, but not optional because it is required. the undefined should be upon start for the placeholder, or if there is another way to render it with placeholder & a value of 0 (because I can't set it as undefined)

i am going to write you an answer how to do this, but I recommend you to add the placeholder part because  the root of your problem is not clear and maybe I can help you for a better solution

Using z.optional():
If you want to choose between a value and undefined, z.optional() works exactly like that. Here's an example:
const schema = z.optional(z.string());

schema.parse(undefined); // => returns undefined
type A = z.infer<typeof schema>; // string | undefined

This means it chooses between String or Undefined. The problem here is: in JavaScript, there's no difference between Undefined and a non-existent array item:
let obj ={};
console.log( Object.is(obj.notExistsItem,undefined) ) // output:  true

Solution:
However, you can choose between string and an empty string "" or 0, you can combine  z.or() and z.literal()
let arr = [
  {
    coachNotes: "",
    repsNumber: "",
    setsNumber: "",
    restTime: "",
    exerciseDetails: "",
  },
  {
    coachNotes: "String",
    repsNumber: 12432,
    setsNumber: 2342,
    restTime: 12,
    exerciseDetails: "string",
  }
]

const schema = z.array(
  z.object({
    coachNotes: z.string().min(2).or(z.literal('')),
    repsNumber: z.number().int().min(1).or(z.literal('')),
    setsNumber: z.number().int().min(1).or(z.literal('')),
    restTime: z.optional(z.number().int().min(1)).or(z.literal('')),
    exerciseDetails: z.string().or(z.literal('')),
  })
);

console.log(schema.safeParse(arr));

There are also other methods related to null and undefined that you might find useful:
const E = z.string().nullable(); // equivalent to nullableString
type E = z.infer<typeof E>; // string | null
    
const nullishString = z.string().nullish(); // string | null | undefined
// equivalent to
z.string().nullable().optional();
    
// empty types
z.undefined();
z.null();
z.void(); // accepts undefined

